# Sting builder - remove all html tags except <br>

Tags: java, html, regex, string, groovy

I have a string builder object "sb" that looks like -

```
Hello.  How can I help you?<br>I don't know<br>Use the link <a 
href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a><br>
```

This is just a sample and it can have any kinds of html tags. How do I remove all possible HTML tags from the object except the br tag.

I have been trying to use the below code to remove all html tags from the sb object, but it doesn't seem to work. Also, not sure how to make an exception for br tag.

```
sb.replaceAll("<.*?>", "");
```

Comment: don't use regex for html

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/7294647

Comment: Yes one should not use regex for parsing html as html may contain nested structures which can't be handled by regex properly. But in this case OP can use regex if all he wants to do is replace all (starting and closing) tags other than `<br>` tag with empty string. People claiming not to use regex for HTML, can any of them give a logical valid reason in this case? Why can't OP use regex for removing all tags from HTML? I am sincerely looking for a logical answer.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I agree. Can you please provide me with your solution.

Comment: @ComplexData: Sure, let me add an answer.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Can we just use a syntax where we remove everything between < > and just not remove <br>

Comment: @ComplexData: Yes you can exactly do that. Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54713986/2102956)

Answer (score 2):

Like we all know, parsing HTML with regex is strongly discouraged if you are trying to capture full tag data and trying to manipulate it. But if you are trying to just strip out all the tags, or conditionally some tags, like in this case, you want to remove all tags except `<br>` tag, you can use this regex,

```
<\/?(?!br>)\w+[^>]*>
```

**Explanation:**

- `<` - Match starting of tag
- `\/?` - Optionally match `/` for matching closing tag
- `(?!br>)` - Reject the match if tag name is `br`
- `\w+` - Match any tag name consisting of word characters
- `[^>]*` - Optionally allow tag attributes to match
- `>` - Match closing of tag

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Tw0w5/1)**

Sample Java codes,

```
String s = "Hello.  How can I help you?<br>I don't know<br>Use the link <a \r\n" + 
        "href=\"www.google.com\" target=\"_blank\">Google</a></br>Hello.  <sometag>somedata</sometag> hey <br1>somedata</br2> hello <1br>somedata</1br> How can I help you?<br>I don't know<br>Use the link <a \r\n" + 
        "href=\"www.google.com\" target=\"_blank\">Google</a></br>";

System.out.println(s.replaceAll("</?(?!br>)\\w+[^>]*>", ""));
```

Prints this where it removes all tags except `<br>` and `</br>`,

```
Hello.  How can I help you?<br>I don't know<br>Use the link Google</br>Hello.  somedata hey somedata hello somedata How can I help you?<br>I don't know<br>Use the link Google</br>
```

Edit: As mentioned by [Lino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5515060/lino) in his comment, if your tag name has optional space around `br` text, you can use following regex which allows optional spaces,

```
<\s*\/?\s*(?!br\s*>)\w+[^>]*>
```

**[Demo allowing optional space in br tag](https://regex101.com/r/2Tw0w5/3)**

Comment: Should I use - sb.replaceAll("<\/?(?!br>)\w+[^>]*>", ""); This is throwing syntax error

Comment: @ComplexData: In Java you need to escape \ and write \\. Let me give you a working regex code in Java.

Comment: I think you need some spaces at the beginning: `< br >` is a valid tag name (at least I think)

Comment: @Lino: Although, I've never seen tags with spaces around the tag name. But it is very trivial to handle that. Just have `\s*` in the regex. [Check this updated regex](https://regex101.com/r/2Tw0w5/3)

Answer (score 0):

parsing HTML using `regex` is not good idea. if you are sure it is HTML always i would suggest you to use `Jsoup` it will automatically consume your html and gives back the document.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(sb.toString());
printChilds(doc.body().childNodes());

    public static void printChilds(List<Node> node)
    {
        for (Node n : node)
        {
            if (n.childNodeSize() == 0)
                System.out.print(n.toString());
            else
                printChilds(n.childNodes());
        }
    }
```

will output `Hello. How can I help you?<br>I don't know<br>Use the link Google<br>`

Comment: Can we just use a syntax where we remove everything between < > and just not remove <br>

Comment: Yes we can, give some time to recall the methods i'll update my answer.

Comment: If you already rely on Jsoup, why not just use `Jsoup.clean`?

Comment: `Jsoup.clean` will return only the plain text with out any well known html tag and problem statement says it needs the `<br>` tag.